# Idiomatic expression for "first working version"?

Tags: idiom-requests

I'm looking for an idiomatic expression for "first working version".

"Prototype" is not correct, since there can be many prototypes.  The phrase I can't seem to bring to mind has "first" in it, I think.  For a telescope or synchrotron they'd call it "first light", but that doesn't make sense for a software tool.  Similar to "first blush" or "first pass", but trendier, somehow.  Think "Eureka!" crossed with "it works!" with "it needs to be cleaned up" mixed in.

Anyone?

Comment: There's a big difference between the first one that kind of works, and the first one that works without any serious issue. This is particularly true of software where it may initially work with limited functionality in one sunny-day scenario, but a lot more work is needed to handle corner cases and fix bugs and defects.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe ***first iteration*** is what you are looking for?

*[Iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration)* itself comes from the world of math but is also used in computing

User pyotr777 on the [forum](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/slow-first-iteration-of-cudnn-convoultion-operations/202362) of the manufacturer of graphical processing units reports:

> "[...]observing some slowdown on the first iteration of CNN training.
> After GPU is warmed up to 100% of SM frequency, I am calling cuDNN
> functions for performing convolutional layer computations.
>
> I am performing the same operation several times consequently, and the
> first iteration in most of the cases (but not always) is slower to up
> to about several times, compared to the consecutive iterations. [...]"

This crowdfunding campaign for RPG game "[Kaigaku](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1059971838/kaigaku-a-samurai-rpg)" has a *pledge US$ 500 or more* which states:

> "You and a group of up to four of your friends all get to run the
> first iteration of adventures before they're published. Your PCs are
> going to figure into the story, once it's published, as NPCs"

thus advertising an ability to play the game with incomplete story-telling elements

But this can also be used outside the math and computer world for various first-time activities

For example [West Point](https://www.westpoint.edu/news/west-point-news/cadets-complete-first-iteration-air-assault-training) military academy informs that *"Cadets complete the first iteration of Air Assault training"*, explaining in the article that:

> "U.S. Military Academy cadets perform rappelling operations from UH-60
> Black Hawks and the Height tower during Air Assault School training
> [...]. This was the first of five iterations, 14 days per session, of
> the Air Assault School at West Point [...]"

Answer (score 1):

We use ***[proof of concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_concept)*** (POC or PoC) to mean this all the time at my work. I think its pretty common business speak nowadays.

> also known as proof of principle, is a realization of a certain method or idea in order to demonstrate its feasibility, or a demonstration in principle with the aim of verifying that some concept or theory has practical potential. A proof of concept is usually small and may or may not be complete.

[Wikipedia]

Answer (score 1):

Minimum viable product?

> Minimum viable product (MVP) is a development technique that introduces a new product in its iteration with only enough features or basic functions to attract customers. By introducing the basic version to customers and potential investors, your company can gauge their response. Based on feedback, the product is then revised and rolled out in its final version.

> The use of MVPs evolved from the Lean Startup methodology of determining if the business model is viable and reducing the amount of time spent in product development phases. It allows companies to test their products at a low cost with minimum resources. Seeing what people do with a product is much more reliable than asking people what they would do.

https://www.indeed.com/career-advice/career-development/minimum-viable-product